# unable to record desktop using latest gstreamer in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: video, encoding, linux

I can broadcast my desktop to a rtmp server successfully using

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc use-damage=0 show-pointer=false ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc ! queue ! flvmux name=mux ! queue ! progressreport ! queue ! rtmpsink sync=false async=true location="rtmp://xxxxxx" pulsesrc do-timestamp=true device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! queue ! audioconvert ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue ! mux.
```

But If I try to do same using hw acceleration vaapi then it does not work !!

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc use-damage=0 show-pointer=false ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! queue ! vaapih264enc dct8x8=true cabac=true rate-control=cbr bitrate=1000 keyframe-period=30 max-bframes=1 ! queue ! flvmux name=mux ! queue ! progressreport ! queue ! rtmpsink sync=false async=true location="rtmp://xxxx" pulsesrc do-timestamp=true device="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" ! queue ! audioconvert ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue ! mux.
```

It is just stuck at below if i use hw acceleration:

> letting pipeline to PAUSED ... Pipeline is live and does not need
> PREROLL ... Got context from element 'vaapiencodeh264-0':
> gst.vaapi.Display=context,
> gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"(GstVaapiDisplayGLX)
> vaapidisplayglx0"; Pipeline is PREROLLED ... Setting pipeline to
> PLAYING ... Redistribute latency... New clock: GstPulseSrcClock